# How can I get coordinates of a place I type in a search bar

Tags: javascript, html, mapping, location, coordinates

I want to be able to type in a town or city in my search bar and have the website return the coordinates of that place. As of right how I only have a very basic outline to work with

```
      <h1>SNOW LOAD</h1>
      <label for="city-input">Enter Place:</label>
      <input type="text" id="city-input" placeholder="e.g., town">
      <button onclick="lookupSnowLoadGroup()">Lookup</button>
      <p id="result"></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Probably you are looking for google maps api?

Comment: https://openweathermap.org/api/geocoding-api#direct - openweathermap API is free, and will give you latitude and longitude coordinates in in the response object.
You are going to end up doing a 'fetch' request based on the user input in your 'search bar'.